# How to filter ~[T]

Tags: rust

This doesn't seems to work for me (rust-0.10)

```
let x : ~[uint] = ~[1,2,3];
let sieved: ~[uint] = x.iter().filter(|&n| 3 % n == 0).collect();
...
prob0003.rs:49:77: 49:78 error: mismatched types: expected `<generic integer #5>` but found `&uint` (expected &-ptr but found integral variable)
prob0003.rs:49  let x : ~[uint] = ~[1,2,3]; let sieved: ~[uint] = x.iter().filter(|&n| 3 % n == 0).collect();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your `collect()` call. The iterator is over `&uint`, and so `collect()` would expect to produce something like `~[&uint]`.

You should change it to use `move_iter()` instead of `iter()`, or else put in a `.map(|&n| n)`.